# Select items programmatically in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController`:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.pageTastes count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CellTasteCollectionView *cell = 
       [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" 
                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];
     Taste *taste = [self.pageTastes objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];       
     [[cell imageView] setImage:taste.image];
     [cell setObjectId:taste.objectId];    
     return cell;
}
```

It works. I have this in `viewDidLoad`, allowing the user to choose multiple items:

```
[self.collectionView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
```

What I want to have, is that the first time the CollectionView loads, some items get selected programmatically, based on their `objectId` in `CellTasteCollectionView`.

Here's how I'm doing this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
         didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Taste *taste = [self.pageTastes objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    printf("%s\n", [taste.objectId UTF8String]);
}
```

It's called when the user clicks on the item -- this is not what I want: I want the item to be selected automatically when `UICollectionView` loads.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you are missing this method from the [UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                     animated:(BOOL)animated 
               scrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

You can use this method multiple times if you want multiple selections.

Comment: Be aware that calling this method programmatically will not trigger collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:.

Answer (score 12):

`didSelectItemAt` is not called if you call `selectItem` programmatically. You should call the method manually after it.

```
self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.districtTableview selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
[self tableView:weakSelf.districtTableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I used the above method in tableview, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For right behaviour call 4 function in a row:

```
// Deselect
self.collection.deselectItem(at: previousPath, animated: true)
self.collectionView(self.collection, didDeselectItemAt: previousPath)

// Select
self.collection.selectItem(at: path, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
self.collectionView(self.collection, didSelectItemAt: path)
```