# How to select item/cell of UICollectionView from code

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented a `UICollectionView` in my app. My problem is that I need to select (like if the user tapped on it) a cell `programmatically`.
The method:

```
- (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                     animated:(BOOL)animated 
               scrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```

That is part of the `UICollectionView` class is not what i need to call, since this method does not call:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
        didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

It just sets the `selected` property of the cell to `YES`;

Comment: What about calling the method yourself after you selected your cell? You could call [self collectionView:yourView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:yourIndexPath];

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177201/select-items-programmatically-in-uicollectionview

Comment: @ДилянаТодорова Yes. Thanks! I knew about the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` one, but I was looking for a method that is not part od the `UICollectionView Delegate Protocol`. I figured it out. It all works fine now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am calling `[self collectionView:yourView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:yourIndexPath]` to programmatically select a cell.  But in the method cell is always nil.  This works perfectly well when user selects a cell.

Comment: or in swift you could use:

`collectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: someIndexPath)`

Comment: That works, it's a bad practice though to call delegate methods directly (the Collection View should invoke that method on its delegate as Apple recommends). As @leviathan mentioned "[selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:] " will not invoke the delegate method so there are better ways to work around that.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is proper behaviour. Documentation for `[selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:]` [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/selectItemAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a):

> This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to
>   be called.

Answer (score 7):

First, you need to make the target cell visible, otherwise `[yourCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:yourIndexPath]` always returns nil.

```
// scroll to the cell
[yourCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:yourIndexPath
                           atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom 
                                   animated:NO];

// call delegate method
[self collectionView:yourCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:yourIndexPath];

// now you have selected the cell and can do anything to it in the delegate method :-)
```

Comment: My cell is always visible, but the cellForItemAtIndexPath always return nil (even after call scrollToItemAtIndexPath